# How do I open a file in google drive using its api?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-drive-api

I'm trying to display a text file from google drive in a textarea.
From what I understand there is no direct way to do it; you have to download it using xhr request. I have tried the code that google provide in their documentation [https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get][1] but with no success.

The Error I'm getting is "500 (Internal Server Error)"
The code is the exact the same as in the google's example. Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure you have an access token before sending the request? And are you using the [example JavaScript provided](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples)?

[Authorizing Your App with Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth):

> All requests to the Google Drive API must be authorized by an authenticated user.

Comment: I'm using the example JavaScript code from Google. Pretty sure I'm authorized since I have implement realtime api and it is working fine.